# Highlight cell if value is present in any cell in another column

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I want to highlight the cell in column A if it is repeated anywhere in column B. For example:

```
A      | B
pack_1 | unrelated
pack_2 | unrelated
pack_3 | pack_1
pack_4 | pack_1
pack_5 | pack_3
pack_6 | pack_3
pack_7 | unrelated
pack_8 | pack_2
```

In the example, `pack_1`, `pack_2` and `pack_3` should be highlighted because they are mentioned in column B.

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: furman87, your solution is exactly what I need. I would select it as answer if I could.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do conditional formatting on each cell with the formula:

```
=EQ(VLOOKUP(A1, B:B, 1, FALSE), A1)
```

And format the cell to a different color if it matches.

I shared an example here (this link will ask you to make a copy in your own Google Drive account):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IovLko1cF2guKnIalCyE0uSbCvMDYLgL0BZHt35znXI/copy

Answer (score 17):

Please select ColumnA, Format, Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is:

```
=match(A1,B:B,0)>0
```

with formatting of choice.

Comment: This works. Additionally I need to set 'Apply to range' to 'A1:A1090', which is applies the rule to that range for my case. Note that the other answer works too but this formula looks simpler =)

Answer (score 2):

You would add conditional formatting to A1 and then copy to rest of the cells in the column.
Set the conditional formatting to custom formula and make the formula:

**=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$8,A1)**

And set your color.
It will highlight the cells in the A column if they exist in the B column.
(Keep in mind I Am assuming your range is B1:B8)

Answer (score -1):

1. Select both columns
2. click Conditional Formatting
3. click Highlight Cells Rules
4. click Duplicate Values (the defaults should be OK)
5. Duplicates are now highlighted in red:

[image: Example. Duplicates are highlighted in red]

Comment: we're in google sheets, not excel